# mediawiki run an extension(ClipUpload) only in specific pages

Tags: php, mediawiki

I have a mediawiki for my team up and running.

[Extension:ClipUpload](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ClipUpload) is a useful extension which allows users to upload images in clipboard by simple copy&paste. 
However, it sometimes causes unwanted uploading of clipboard (e.g. text copied from excel or other MS office softwares)

So what I want is making a specific page so that I use the ClipUpload extension in specific pages.

Here's what I have done but failed:

1. created a page: http://my.domain/wiki/index.php/UploadFromClipboard
2. when I enter the edit page: http://my.domain/wiki/index.php?title=UploadFromClipboard&action=edit
3. I wanted to run the extension so added a line in LocalSettings.php

   if ( preg_match("/(Clipboard)/i", $wgArticlePath) ) require_once("$IP/extensions/ClipUpload/ClipUpload.php");
4. This type of solution did not work. The problem is I can't parse page title in query.

Could you please suggest some solutions that I can try?

Answer (score 0):

`LocalSettings.php` is loaded before MediaWiki parses the URL and there are enough edge cases that you shouldn't want to do it yourself.

One option is to use something that runs early but after basic variables have been set up (like [BeforeInitialize](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/BeforeInitialize)) and disable the extension there based on the title (something like `$wgHooks['EditPage::showEditForm:initial'] = array_diff( $wgHooks['EditPage::showEditForm:initial'], [ 'ClipSetup' ] );`.

Or you might try to fix the extension / file a bug (discarding clipboard content that's not an image seems pretty trivial).

Comment: Thanks, Tgr. I will report this bug to the developer first and look more details into the variables you suggested.